# mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean error but the result of the query is varchar

Tags: php

I am having the below error when accessing this link:
(yes I know Ill use `json` later because it is better but I am trying this)
http://justedhak.comlu.com/insert.php?username=m&password=m

```
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/a6901827/public_html/insert.php on line 18
```

but the result of this query is varchar not boealan res is varchar and the query will gives result 'yes' .. why then I am having such error ?

```
<?php
$host='mysql12.000webhost.com';
$uname='z';
$pwd='6';
$db="a6901827";


$con = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT res FROM samle where 
name='$username' and password='$password'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];

if($data){
echo $data;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are open to sql injections with this code. Your code doesn't work because you are sending a `GET` request but looking for `POST` data.

```
<?php
$host='mysql12.000webhost.com';
$uname='****';
$pwd='*****';
$db="******";    
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['password']);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT res FROM samle where 
name='$username' and password='$password'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];

if($data){
echo $data;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Also..

1. You should consider using prepared statements in the future.
2. You should not store passwords in plain text.
3. When posting code be sure to remove credentials.
4. You also could use `$_REQUEST`, then POST, GET, or COOKIE could be used.

Comment: Yes yes I kow I am just reading tutorials about post and get , I am new to php and I am using it with android @chris85